# Could not exec dpkg! E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100) in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I accidently closed terminal when i am uninstalled mysql with `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` 
then open new terminal and run `sudo apt-get upgrade` that getting errors in Ubuntu.

Here is the detail errors:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
/tmp/grub-efi-amd64.config.lyQJMF: 1: /tmp/grub-efi-amd64.config.lyQJMF: dpkg: not found
/tmp/gdm3.config.K21eTR: 23: /tmp/gdm3.config.K21eTR: dpkg: not found
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

I try fixed errors with `chmod 755 /usr/bin/dpkg or sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/dpkg` but it does not work. It is the same.

Here the output is : `chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/dpkg': No such file or directory`

Run file $(which dpkg) getting ouput is:

`$ file $(which dpkg) Usage: file [-bcEhikLlNnprsvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type] [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ... file -C [-m magicfiles] file [--help]`

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you please run `file $(which dpkg)` and  add the output to your question?

Comment: https://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/debian-apt-get-installs-fail-with-dpkg-error-code-100/

Comment: @Simon Sudler, Here is the detail result after run that  `file $(which dpkg)` ::~$ file $(which dpkg)
Usage: file [-bcEhikLlNnprsvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type]
            [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ...
       file -C [-m magicfiles]
       file [--help]

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, it doesn't work . Here the ouput is : `chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/dpkg': No such file or directory
 `

Comment: Please [edit] en update  your question with both results. Apparently you have serious problem. If you remember  what happened, what you did before noticing the problem post that as well.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, i already edit it. Please let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: I think `dpkg` somehow was removed. It won't hurt doing `sudo apt install dpkg`. If it actually installs then `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: It does not work with sudo apt install dpkg adn getting errors:
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  debsig-verify
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dpkg
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 159 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,140 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)`